# 413 Request Entity Too Large: Nginx/1.16.1

Tags: nginx, supervisord

Не могу загрузить видео на сервер больше ~20 мб, ошибка 413. Перепробовал уже массу вариантов. client_max_body_size устанавливал везде, где только можно и где нельзя. php и apache не использую. Используются nginx + gunicorn + supervisor.

nginx.conf:

```
worker_processes 2;

user www;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
    accept_mutex       off;
    use                epoll;
    multi_accept       on;
}

http {
    charset utf-8;
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    sendfile                  on;
    keepalive_timeout         30;
    keepalive_requests        100;
    tcp_nopush                on;
    tcp_nodelay               on;
    client_max_body_size      0;
    client_body_buffer_size 100m;
    client_body_timeout       10;
    send_timeout              2;
    reset_timedout_connection on;

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
    gzip_vary on;

    upstream django {
        server unix:/tmp/gunicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
    }

    upstream supervisor {
        server unix:/tmp/supervisor.sock fail_timeout=0;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name localhost;
        charset utf-8;
        keepalive_timeout 5;
        client_max_body_size 0;
        client_body_buffer_size 100m;
        client_body_timeout 600;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;

        location /static {
            alias /opt/app/collected_static;
            expires 30d;
        }

        location /media {
            alias /opt/app/media;
            expires 30d;
        }

        location / {
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Scheme http;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto http;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_connect_timeout 600;
            proxy_send_timeout 600;
            proxy_read_timeout 600;
            send_timeout 600;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_pass http://django;
            proxy_pass_header Server;
        }

        location /supervisor/ {
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host/supervisor/index.html;
            rewrite ^/supervisor(.*)$ /$1 break;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_buffering off;
            proxy_pass https://supervisor/;

            auth_basic "Supervisor";
            auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
        }
    }
}
```

supervisor.conf:

```
[supervisord]
logfile = /var/log/supervisord.log
loglevel = info
directory = /opt/app
pidfile = /tmp/supervisord.pid
nodaemon = true
minfds = 65535
minprocs = 200
environment = PATH="/opt/app"
user = root

[unix_http_server]
file = /tmp/supervisor.sock ; (the path to the socket file)
chmod = 777                ; sockef file mode (default 0700)

[supervisorctl]
serverurl = unix:///tmp/supervisor.sock ; use a unix:// URL for a unix socket

[rpcinterface:supervisor]
supervisor.rpcinterface_factory = supervisor.rpcinterface:make_main_rpcinterface

[program:nginx]
priority = 1
command = /usr/sbin/nginx "-g" "daemon off;"
autorestart = true
stdout_events_enabled = true
stderr_events_enabled = true

[program:gunicorn]
command = /usr/bin/gunicorn -b unix:/tmp/gunicorn.sock Project.wsgi:application --workers=2 --worker-class=meinheld.gmeinheld.MeinheldWorker
priority = 2
stdout_logfile = /var/log/gunicorn.log
redirect_stderr = true
stdout_events_enabled = true
stderr_events_enabled = true
autorestart = true
```

В проекте всего 3 докер контейнера: web, db, redis. Nginx находится в web вместе с бэкендом.

Страшный Dockerfile контейнера web:

```
FROM alpine:3.11

COPY requirements.txt /opt/app/requirements.txt

RUN apk update && apk add --update --no-cache --progress \
    make \
    pcre \
    zlib \
    openssl \
    ca-certificates \
      py3-pillow \
      py3-cffi \
      py3-brotli \
      musl-dev \
      pango \
      python3 \
      python2-dev \
      python3-dev \
    postgresql-dev \
    gcc \
    libffi-dev \
    openssl-dev \
    cargo \
    supervisor \
    cyrus-sasl-dev \
    jpeg libpng freetype  \
      bash bash-completion \
      gettext-dev \
      geos \
    proj \
    gdal \
    binutils \
      nginx \
      postgis \
    wkhtmltopdf \
    nano \

      && ln -s /usr/lib/libproj.so.15 /usr/lib/libproj.so \
    && ln -s /usr/lib/libgdal.so.20 /usr/lib/libgdal.so \
    && ln -s /usr/lib/libgeos_c.so.1 /usr/lib/libgeos_c.so \

    && apk add --no-cache --virtual=.build-dependencies \
      musl-dev \
      build-base \
      zlib-dev \
      pcre-dev \
      jpeg-dev libpng-dev freetype-dev \
      python2-dev \
      python3-dev \

    && python3 -m ensurepip \
    && rm -r /usr/lib/python*/ensurepip \
    && export CRYPTOGRAPHY_DONT_BUILD_RUST=1 \
    && pip3 install --upgrade pip \
    && pip3 install --upgrade setuptools==58.2 \
    && pip3 install --no-cache-dir -r /opt/app/requirements.txt \

    # Add nginx group and user
    && addgroup -S www \
    && adduser -S www -G www \
    && apk del .build-dependencies \
    && chown -R www:www /var/lib/nginx/tmp \
    && chown -R www:www /var/lib/nginx \
    && echo "root:$(openssl passwd -apr1 6zpDyBiK)" >> /etc/nginx/.htpasswd

COPY . /opt/app
VOLUME ["/opt/app/media"]
WORKDIR /opt/app

RUN rm -v /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
ADD Deploy/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["/bin/bash", "./Deploy/start_in_docker.sh"]
```

Весь проект работает за исключением загрузки больших файлов. Еще я пробовал вставлять client_max_body_size в блок location в nginx.conf и там же менять proxy_pass на localhost:8000 без upstream и gunicorn сокета, проблема та же.

И nginx смотрит на правильный файл конфигурации, команда nginx -t дает положительный результат и верный путь до файла.

В файле error.log nginx пишет ошибки:

1. writev() failed (32: Broken pipe) while sending request to upstream
2. readv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading upstream

Возникают эти ошибки беспорядочно, но только при загрузке файлов от ~20мб

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в gunicorn в файле supervisor.conf

Убрал из "command" --worker-class=meinheld.gmeinheld.MeinheldWorker

Осталось:
command = /usr/bin/gunicorn -b unix:/tmp/gunicorn.sock Project.wsgi:application --workers=2

Теперь все работает